# Fit code inside slide using chunk global options in Rmarkdown knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, chunks

I am trying to format my Rmd presentation created in RStudio.

I can see that in some of my code chunks code is longer than slide so 
some parts of it are not showing.

Had some reading on global options chunk and tried to put this:

`{r, global_options, include=FALSE}
    library(knitr)
    library(formatR)
    opts_chunk$set(
      echo=TRUE,
      warning=FALSE,
      message=FALSE,
      tidy = TRUE,
      tidy.opts=list(blank=FALSE, width.cutoff=60,size = 'tiny'),
      fig.width=5, 
      fig.height=4, 
      fig.path='Figs/')`

but this is not changing nothing in my chunks.

Can you please help
Regards

Comment: correct. Which type of presentation are you using? The solution to fitting them is per-pres-type. Note that the smaller you make the code the more unreadable it will be (i.e. almost pointless to do it). Why not split code on multiple slides?

Comment: I am using beamer_presentation so I knit Pdf. My problem is breaking commands in more than one line..keeping it understandable..

Comment: See if this helps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/decrease-font-size-in-a-listing (my latex is a bit rusty but if that doesn't I may be able to hack something).

Comment: Yes in sweave(latex) there are plenty of listing configurations. But I want to do it in Rmd files. Thanks anyway

Comment: But you're using Beamer, which is turning markdown into latex to PDF. You can't use CSS or chunk options to control what you want to control. You have to tweak at the latex level. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html